# Android.Gradle: How create task that execute another tasks in strict sequence?

Tags: android, gradle

Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 4.2

When I want to create distributive (**apk**) and upload it to Fabric (Beta by CrashLytics) I use the next Gradle command:

```
gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

OK. It's work.

Now I want to create my custom task that will start this two commands in **strict** sequence.

First **assembleRelease**  and then **crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease**.

How I can do this by Gradle?

Comment: make `crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease` dependent on `assembleRelease` and just run `crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease`

Comment: I want to create custom task with short name that it depends on **assembleRelease**  and **crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease**  in strong sequence. How I can do this?

Comment: Is this a correct solution: `task myTaskRelease(dependsOn: [assembleRelease, crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease ]) {
                }`
?